# ReadAllbytes method not finishing - network stream

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have this `ReadAllBytes` method which is supposed to read certain amount
of bytes from `NetworkStream`

```
private void ReadAllBytes(byte[] buffer, int length)
{
    if (buffer.Length != length)
        throw new Exception("WriteBytes: Length should be same");

    Stream stm = m_client.GetStream();

    // Start reading
    int offset = 0;
    int remaining = length;
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        int read = stm.Read(buffer, offset, remaining);
        if (read <= 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException
                (String.Format("ReadAllBytes: End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
        remaining -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
}
```

The thing is it works most of the times, but sometimes when program enters this function, it never returns and seems to run forever. I found out this using logging. I use it like:

```
public TcpClient m_client = new TcpClient();
m_client.Connect(IP,port);
ReadAllBytes(lengthArray, 2);
```

Can someone help me what is the problem? I think it is related to *timeouts*, but how to be sure? and how to fix this?

Can it be related to how I am disposing this class?

I also don't get any exceptions.

Comment: You get the error when the size of the network stream exceed the length ?

Comment: If  lengths should be equal, why bother adding a parameter `length`? just use `buffer.Length`.

Comment: what's lengthArray ?

Comment: @amitdayama: Just a byte array

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: true but that doesn't help me now

Comment: @RomEh: I don't get any errors, just program seems to wait for something infinitely

Comment: quite possible your program was getting timeout at m_client.Connect(IP,port); Did you debug your code and checked it?

Comment: That method seems fine. How certain are you that the stream can deliver as many bytes as you think it should? Is the sender guaranteed to send the right amount?

Comment: @usr: It should - but what can be causing it to wait indefinitely? A timeout? Should I change the read time out property maybe of tcp client?

Comment: @amitdayama: as I said it hangs during reading

Comment: "but what can be causing it to wait indefinitely?" not enough bytes coming in. That's the only reason Read blocks. Find out why there are not enough bytes. The question cannot be answered with the information given.

Comment: @usr: Should it hang forever than? I just changed Read time out value to some thing and it seems more stable now. Documentation said default Read time out is infinite. Was it correct approach to solve this problem? At least I hope to get exception if data doesn't arrive

Comment: The bug is that not enough data is there. It's a **bug**. A timeout does not fix a bug, it's a way to break the read so that the app does not hang forever if the network goes down (and also so that bugs are not catastrophic). Fix the bug. But also keep the timeout.

Comment: @usr: Yes but I prefer that I get exception instead forever wait - to fix this I should introduce timeout? Also I can't fix that bug because that is on the server side and I haven't access there - also I don't see that bug occurring when I am using the existing C++ project? So maybe it is C# thing? (I am just rewriting that C++ project to C# which is similarly communicating with the server)

Comment: "also I don't see that bug occurring when I am using the existing C++ project" This means the bug is in *your C# code*. It's not a C# thing, read can't work any other way in principle.

Comment: @Quser: `Read()` will never return unless the connection is lost or if data is received. there is no way around that with blocking sockets. Either accept that or switch to non-blocking sockets are the async read methods.

Comment: @jgauffin: The strange thing is I didn't observe such behaviour from existing C++ project which tries to do same thing. Do you see some problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210429/netowork-connection-works-most-of-the-times-but-sometimes-my-program-doesnt-f, that is my full C# code basically.

Answer (score 0):

That method seems fine. How certain are you that the stream can deliver as many bytes as you think it should? Is the sender guaranteed to send the right amount?

The bug is that not enough data is there. It's a bug. A timeout does not fix a bug, it's a way to break the read so that the app does not hang forever if the network goes down (and also so that bugs are not catastrophic). Fix the bug. But also keep the timeout just in case.

> also I don't see that bug occurring when I am using the existing C++ project

This means the bug is in your C# code. It's not a C# thing, read can't work any other way in principle. What do you think is read supposed to do when there is no data? It can either wait or fail. No other choices.

The fact that you have called Read when there is no data coming is your bug/problem/fault. Not Reads fault.

> should introduce timeout; Yes but I prefer that I get exception instead forever wait

Yes, a timeout is always required when it comes to network communication in case the network goes down (or in case you have a bug and don't want to hang forever). Always have a timeout.

Comment: You say it is bug in my C# code, but I basically showed you my C# code. Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210429/netowork-connection-works-most-of-the-times-but-sometimes-my-program-doesnt-f, for more details on my network class. If you can point that bug there, I will accept that answer too, as well as this one.

Comment: The bug is not visible here. It is elsewhere. The reading function is OK. The problem is that there is too little data left in the stream. Either not enough has been sent or you have read too much elsewhere.

Comment: You mean it is not visible also in the other question I linked to? That is basically my full network class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210429/netowork-connection-works-most-of-the-times-but-sometimes-my-program-doesnt-f. please have a look at that also

Comment: OK, I forgot to look there. That code looks very good. In fact better than most socket code that I have seen. I can't see any issue. Probably, the sender is broken and your other C++ client has a bug when receiving. It should block/hang but it does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice words!! Actually now that I added time out on the C# side, it works much more stable, no more hangs, what do you think??

Comment: The bug is still there and you are probably loosing data in some way.

Comment: Why do you think so? Actually I have my protocol implemented, and if there were a byte missing I think I would spot that during serialization/deserialization (I use TLV scheme). also there are signatures coming and if byte were missing, signatures would not match. What do you think? Also my read methods read exact amount of bytes

Comment: What's your current theory on why Read is hanging? You have to acknowledge **there is no data**.

Comment: Yeah but after I added the read time out - there is no more hanging occuring. I tested with making transactions 40 times for example and no single hang

Comment: What you think now(after my last comment)?

Comment: Well, you haven't gotten the data that your code needed. Not sure how the code is supposed to continue. You can post the new code if you want.

Comment: I think we have miscommunication. I meant after I added timeouts to reading there is no more hanging on the C# side

Comment: Yeah, because the timeout exception breaks the reading, right?

Comment: Neither did I get an exception(I tested 40 times that is what I meant)

Comment: If you set a timeout the only effect it can have is to throw an exception. That exception might have happened somewhere else and might have been suppressed. Use "break on all exceptions" to find out. If this does not turn up anything I don't think I can do anything more because some piece of the puzzle is missing.

Comment: yes I understand but basically setting time out solved the hanging problem. I thought maybe at some point even on small problem previous solution was going to infinite wait, smth like that maybe? But anyway this way it seems working now, so maybe I should just go on??